# Objects disappear when looking through camera

Tags: 3d-view, camera

When I go to camera perspective, there are parts of my object that I can't see. I tried adding and deleting my camera a lot of times and positioning it so that the objects I would like to see on my camera view will be seen but to no avail, I still get the same problem.

What could be wrong with my camera set-up?

[image: User Ortho View]
[image: Camera Perspective View]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I guess this is a **clipping distance** issue. Select your *Camera*, go to the *Camera Data* tab and check the *End* value of your *Clipping Range*.

**Blender 2.8x**

[image]

**Blender 2.7x**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that you are not rendering or viewing all of your layers. According the the posted image, the are several layers with images that aren't visible. Press the key above tab to view all layers.

Comment: Ah, thank you for editing the title. 
The layers I made visible are the layers I want to see through my camera, isn't that how it works? (I'm new to Blender) As seen in the first picture, I'm supposed to see the second floor of the building but it's not appearing on camera view.