# I can only see a few feet ahead in Game engine

Tags: camera

Look at the link, This is how I want mine to be.

[A youtube clip of a blender game.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGhDONzY-BM)

this is my error
I am working on a game similar to Zelda / Mario games.
in the 3d world. But I do not get the image / video to be fine.
I only see a few feet ahead. then it's gray
I want to get rid of it.
Hope you understand my question.

Soory My English is not so good.

Edit!
I

//
Robin Willmann

Comment: Welcome to the site :) Sounds like the camera clip end is to low, or you might have mist enabled. Is it possible you could upload a screenshot? BTW, here we like to keep posts focused on one question at a time. If you have multiple unrelated questions, feel free to create multiple posts. This helps keep things organized and easier to read through for other users (like those arriving from google). Thanks :)

Comment: look at this post http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18286/objects-disappear-when-looking-through-camera/18291#18291

Comment: Thank you.
Sorry for many questions.
I had read it. but forgot. (I'm not used to writing on forums and stuff) :)
But anyway
I now manage to get the picture better.
so thank you.


It was clipping that was too low.