# Blender Camera shows gray circle

Tags: camera

I'm new to blender and i need to makee a small 3d platform level for school. I followed a tutorial and built my level inside an UV Sphere so it would get a background image. in my case, to simulate the Space. The problem is, i've done one level already and its all good. But in this second one, whenever i try to switch to camera view, theres this gray circle and i cannot render the texture of the sphere. Whats goin on ?

EDIT: Heres the image:

[image]

EDIT2 : I already changed the clipping end parameter. Still nothing.

EDIT3: [image: Tried clip from 100 to 50000]

Comment: Could you post the .blend file, it makes it much easier to find what is wrong.

Comment: Does it render correctly?

Comment: no, it doenst. Okay ill post it. Do you want me to include the textures ?

Comment: You can [pack the textures](http://cgcookie.com/blender/2009/09/28/tip-packing-blend-files/) into the .blend, which would be best. But it probably isn't necessary.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e62712mncsxisvu/tutorial.blend?dl=0

Comment: It is on the layer 4. The first layer is working. The layer 4 is the exact same tecnique and this happens.

Comment: For me it looks like a clipping issue: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18286/objects-disappear-when-looking-through-camera/18291#18291. You can also try to set the clipping of the viewport by hitting n > View > Clip and raise up the end value.

Comment: Tried that already. Still nothing :S

Comment: I've also tried it at the moment and it works with a camera end clipping value above 140.

Comment: start 0.100 end 150 , doesnt work for me :S

Comment: So u select the Camera in Object mode, then Camera settings on the right menu, End clipp - 150. ?

Comment: Here is an image: http://i.imgur.com/pj6LdOc.png

Comment: @PedroCosta Yes, but in your screenshot you have the wrong camera selected. You probably want to select the one you are viewing from.

Comment: I copied ur settings, Hit CTRL + ALT + numpad0 , then shift + F to move the camera and still the same :O. But i noticed that in ur image u have the stuff from layer 1 rendered. why is that ?

Comment: @gandalf3 the wrong camera ? i just added a new one, selected it and it does the same thing. i've done it countless times xD

Comment: Oh my god i can't believe it. YES @gandalf3 i am so dumb. Okay guys, sorry for wasting ur time with my dumbness...

Comment: @PedroCosta The clipping settings are specific to each camera. Changing them on a new camera won't affect the settings on the current camera. No worries, glad you got it working :)

Comment: @PedroCosta Glad to help you.

Comment: Yeah i just thought i was using that camera. Now i realise that small triangle above the camera. when its highlighted it represents the camera that i am using. I remember reading that in some tutorial. Thank you guys :)