# Cycles is only rendering sky texture and nothing else

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I was in Blender Cycles, I imported an .obj file, worked with it, added some materials to it, and clicked on the little "render" circle right next to Object Mode. I saw the building and the sky and that was what I needed.

When I went to render image, the sky was only in the background, not the building.

Comment: You can try to check your camera settings. Maybe it's a clipping issue, see this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18286/objects-disappear-when-looking-through-camera/18291#18291, but it's just guessing - please provide an image or the blend file.

Comment: Okay, edit. I only see one floor in the entire building. I changed my clipping to be far so that shouldnt be a problem either.

Comment: The little camera icon next to all my objects is dimmed. How do I light it up for all the objects at once? I have about 2000 objects, and would take alot of time if I had to enable one by one.

Comment: I fixed it myself. I had to press a in the Outliner then press r for all of them.

Comment: Pressing A and R is a really nice solution, maybe you want to add this as answer to the duplicate.