# Blender Game not rendering objects correctly

Tags: rendering, game-engine, objects

When I try to play my game, the scene gets messed up. I think it is better if I show you what I mean.

Image:
[image: Incorrect rendering (second image)]

The skydome is completely gone and the order in which the models render is completely wrong. I tried a lot of things, but nothing seems to fix it.

EDIT: The problem with the skydome is fixed. I had to flip the normals.

EDIT #2: Here is a link to the .blend file: http://www.mediafire.com/download/lm3i4n78gcok8q2/Station_of_Awakening.blend

Comment: probably camera clipping issue, check this : http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18291/11431

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't fix it. The problem is not the render distance, but the skydome doesn't render at all.

Comment: try to recalculate or flip the normals, else you'd better upload the blend file

Comment: Yes, thanks, the skydome problem is fixed, but the rest is still messed up.

Comment: post a [.blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: I will in a second.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, haha, I guess I figured it out myself. Sorry.

I fixed the problem by selecting GLSL instead of Multitexture in the Properties > Render > Shading menu. Let me show you:
[image: Fixed]

Comment: glad you found, i was replacing the materials with a simple one with a grid texture and it would take forever :) (can't see anything but pink!)

Comment: Thanks for your help, anyway. Thanks to you I fixed the skydome, even though it has some cutoff :P